# Can we exporting model property with Pydantic model method?

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there a way to export Pydantic (v1.10) models property with [Pydantic model method](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict)?

This is what I want :

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a : int 

    @property
    def square(self):
        return a**2

foo = Foo(a=2)
assert "square" in foo.dict()  
assert foo.dict()["square"]==foo.dict()["a"]**2
```

Comment: Not without significant hacking of the `BaseModel` internals or very brittle and inefficient `dict`/`json` method overrides. Pydantic v2 introduced [computed fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/computed_fields/) for just this purpose.

Comment: this is solved in Pydantic 2: 
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/5502